# Почему бекап таблицы mysql не удается сделать через shell_exec, если скрипт запускается через браузер?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, shell

В php-скрипте через shell_exec запускаю создание дампа таблицы базы данных.

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -u{$selfDbConnectArray['dbuser']} -p{$selfDbConnectArray['dbPassword']} {$selfDbConnectArray['dbName']} $table | gzip > `date +{$rootDir}_service/dbbackups/$folder/$table.%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S.sql.gz`";

shell_exec($cmd);
```

Запускаю php-скрипт через консоль, все прекрасно работает. 
Запускаю скрипт через браузер - mysqldump создает пустой файл, а если использовать gzip сжатие, то файл размером 20Б

Почему? почему не получается через браузер запустить бекап? как это сделать?

Comment: а в логах сервера есть какая нибудь ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь до mysqldump (посмотрите его командой `which mysqldump`). Скорее всего, под веб-сервером в переменной окружения  PATH не указан путь к папке, где лежит mysql.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь аналогом данной функции exec(). Она Вам и ошибку покажет и команду выполнит. Да и не плохо было бы проверить логи.

Comment: $cmd = "cmd.exe /c mysqldump -u{$sel.....sql.gz`";